# solr exception Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr

Hi I am trying to index an entity in solr using spring boot data solr. But i am getting exception

```
    Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/portal: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/portal/publishers/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my publisher class

```
    @SolrDocument
public class Publishers {

    @Id
    @Field
    private String advID;
    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private String domain;
    @Field("cat")
    private String categories;

     //getters and setters
}
```

My repository interface

```
    public interface BookRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Publishers, String> {

    List<Publishers> findByName(String name);
}
```

and my base URL is `"http://localhost:8983/solr/portal"`. In my main class code is like below

```
    @Resource
    BookRepository repository;
 @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
this.repository.save(new Publishers("4", "Sony Playstation","none", null));
}
```

**UPDATED**
I have observed that the entity class i.e `Publishers` name is automatically appending to the URL. I don't know how to tell application not to append the name in solr URL while sending a call to solr.
can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: where and when are you getting that exception?

Comment: when i am saving my publisher please see my run()

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate your solr document as @SolrDocument(solrCoreName="YOU_CORE_NAME")

Answer (score -3):

check you URL is up and correct.